# Converting a timestamp to human readable format in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm attempting to format a timestamp into a more human readable format. Right now I have a variable `"{{ outdated_certs.0.not_after[0:8] }}"` that outputs the following `yyyymmdd`format, e.g.: `20220426`.
What is the best way to re-format this to be more human readable, something like `yyyy-mm-dd` or, in this case, `2022-04-26`?

I have attempted:

- using `to_datetime` like `" {{outdated_certs.0.not_after[0:8]| to_datetime }}"` that results in an error

  > "time data '20220426' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'"
- using `"{{ '%Y-%m-%d' | strftime(outdated_certs.0.not_after[0:8]) }}"` that results in a date of `1970-08-22`, which is more of a epoch time convert, I think

Comment: using pipe: `{{ lookup('pipe', 'date -d ' +VAR_NAME|quote + ' +%Y-%m-%d') }}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt with `to_datetime` was the correct approach.

The only thing you missed is that you have to feed the format of your date to it, so it can understand how to translate the string your are passing into a `datetime`.

Since your format is `yyyymmdd`, you will just have to translate this in the corresponding [Python date format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes), so, in your case `%Y%m%d`.

We end up with a task like:

```yaml
- debug:
    var: >-
      outdated_certs.0.not_after[:8]
      | to_datetime(
        '%Y%m%d'
      )
```

Which would yield:

```yaml
TASK [debug] *****************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  ? |-
    outdated_certs.0.not_after[:8] | to_datetime(
      '%Y%m%d'
    )
  : '2022-04-26 00:00:00'
```

---

From there on, you are getting a `datetime` Python object and can reformat it as you're pleased with the `strftime` filter.

For example:

```yaml
- debug:
    var: >-
      '%c'
      | strftime(
        (
          outdated_certs.0.not_after[:8]
          | to_datetime('%Y%m%d')
        ).timestamp()
      )
```

Would yield:

```yaml
TASK [debug] *****************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  ? |-
    '%c' | strftime(
      (
        outdated_certs.0.not_after[:8]
        | to_datetime('%Y%m%d')
      ).timestamp()
    )
  : Tue Apr 26 00:00:00 2022
```