# Ansible - Convert timestamp to some human readable format

Tags: time, ansible, timestamp

I have a variable with a timestamp which I need to convert to a human readable format.
Here is an example:

```
- name: Extract timestamp from output
  set_fact:
    timestamp: "{{ output.json | json_query(snap_timestamp) }}"
  vars:
    snap_timestamp: "[*].{Timestamp: timestamp}"
```

Output I get is:

```
{
    "msg": "timestamp is [{'Timestamp': 1662628573}]"
}
```

I then tried to convert it with these filters but it doesn't work

```
 - name: Convert timestamp to a human readable format
   set_fact:
      snap_timestamp_converted: "{{ snap_timestamp[0] | to_json | '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' | strftime }}"
```

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Does [Converting a timestamp to human readable format in Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72550841/6771046) answer your question?

Comment: Not really, he already has yyyymmdd format which he wants to convert further. I have this epoch time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax is below. See [Handling dates and times](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#handling-dates-and-times)

```yaml
snap_timestamp_converted: "{{ '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'|strftime(timestamp) }}"
```

For example, the playbook

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    timestamp: 1662628573
    snap_timestamp_converted: "{{ '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'|strftime(timestamp) }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: snap_timestamp_converted
```

gives

```yaml
  snap_timestamp_converted: '2022-09-08 11:16:13'
```